# Copy driver from bluetooth connector Dongle to another

Tags: connector, dongle

So I have a wireless joystick and I've lost the USB Dongle that connect with the PC, My friend has the joystick as mine, is there any solution (software) to copy the driver of his dongle and put it in an old Dongle (Mouse)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.
A driver is software that enables working with one specific device.

You can install any driver on your computer that you like, but it would only
recognize devices that it is built for.

You need to find a dongle that is exactly the same make as the one you lost,
or the one that has your friend.
You might be able to find such a dongle on the internet, if not available locally.

On the other hand, it's possible that you can pair your mouse with
a dongle of a second mouse, but there is no guarantee that it will work.
You will just need to try. But you would need the driver that came with
the second mouse (although many dongles don't need a driver at all).